# Check object permission for user with global permission

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-guardian

How i can check permission to object for user with global permission ?

```
joe = User.objects.get(username="joe")
assign_perm('parse.show_company', joe) # assign global permission
company = Company.objects.get(id=id)

joe.has_perm('parse.show_company', company ) # check permission for object, return False
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an open issue with permission checker in django guardian app. You can find it on github.

https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/issues/294

You can also check global permission for the object with user like below:

```
from guardian.shortcuts import get_objects_for_user
if company in get_objects_for_user(company, 'parse.show_company'):
    # do your stuff
```

I hope this will help you.